# How to get all the buttons to be automatically the same size depending on the largest one in tkinter using canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button

How are you supposed to go around sizing all the buttons to be the same size regardless of the text you insert inside, they should all size according to the biggest one.
There is an answer to a similar question like mine already, but it is done using `grid` and I am using a canvas to place a background image in the window and to place the buttons.

Is it even worth the hassle to get your buttons to the same size according to text automatically, since my text will always be around the same...

I tried getting the size of the buttons using `cget()` but that returns 0. Where does it store its width then since it has to size itself somehow even if it does it according to text? Can access that in any way? I was thinking of using that value to adjust the value of other buttons somehow, but it turned out as a fail.

If you are wondering why am I making it into a class, idk either, wanted to try it.

I had it working by putting all the buttons in a frame and telling them to `fill=x` but using a frame destroys the point of using a canvas since the background can't be seen because the frame covers it. Is there a way to make the frame transparent in the canvas, that could also potentially solve my problem.

```py
from tkinter import *

class ThreeButtonMenu():
    def __init__(self, button1_text, button2_text, button3_text, image_height = 600, image_width = 500, bg_input = 'space_background.png'):

        self.root = Tk()

        HxW = str(image_height)+'x'+str(image_width)
        self.root.geometry(HxW)
        self.root.maxsize(image_height,image_width)
        self.root.minsize(image_height,image_width)

        self.root.title('Guess')

        bg = PhotoImage(file=bg_input)

        background_canvas = Canvas(self.root, width = 600, height=500)
        background_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        background_canvas.create_image(0,0, image=bg, anchor='nw')

        

        button1 = Button(self.root, text=button1_text, font = ('Lato',28))
        button2 = Button(self.root, text=button2_text, font = ('Lato',28))
        button3 = Button(self.root, text=button3_text, font = ('Lato',28), command = self.root.destroy)

        button1_window = background_canvas.create_window(300,45, anchor=N, window=button1)
        button2_window = background_canvas.create_window(300,160, anchor=N, window=button2)
        button3_window = background_canvas.create_window(300,275, anchor=N, window=button3)


        print(button1.cget('width'))
        print(button2.cget('width'))
        print(button3.cget('width'))
           
        self.root.mainloop()


start_menu = ThreeButtonMenu('Start Game', 'Leaderboard', 'Quit')
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically do this when you use a geometry manager (`pack`, `place`, or `grid`).

For example, you need to call `pack` on each of the buttons. See example of `pack` below.

```
    import tkinter as tk
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    for text in (
            "Hello", "short", "All the buttons are not the same size",
            "Options", "Test2", "ABC", "This button is so much larger"):
        button = tk.Button(root, text=text)
        button.pack(side="top", fill="x")
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have read that, but can you use that for a canvas window? I am not sure how to go about implementing that in my code honestly. Do I just take the button_windows and put .pack() on them?

Comment: You will need to pack each button individually.

Comment: I have done it, thank you. Should I delete the question since it was basically a duplicate. Thank you for clearing things up for me!

Comment: I've updated the answer, better to leave it here than delete because someone in future may come across the same problem as yours.